# Javascript: How to replace [ ] and "?

Tags: php, javascript, regex, arrays, split

I am sending a Array from PHP encoded it to JSON and send it to a JavaScript value.
Now I wanted to split the Array on comma's `,`.
This worked fine, but when calling the very first and last string inside the array I can see a `[`, `]` and `"`.

I can get the `"` gone, but the `[` and `]` seems to be a problem.

my code now:

```
data_array[i].replace(/["[]]/g,"");
```

Comment: Don't do that.  You should use a JSON parser.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you transfer a string value like `"[5,4,7,2,1]"` from PHP to Javascript, you should rather `JSON decode` it into a native Javascript object/array.

```
var receivedData = "[5,4,7,2,1]";
    receivedData = JSON.parse( receivedData );
```

From that point on, you may just access `receivedData` like a normal *Array*

```
console.log( receivedData[ 2 ] );  // 7
```

Comment: If `"[5,4,7,2,1]"` is what the transferred string looks like, then it won't get parsed into an Array because of the outer quotes. Your `var receivedData = "[5,4,7,2,1]";` isn't quite equivalent because the `""` syntax doesn't become part of the string. Seems like there's some problem with the JSON encoding on the server that needs to be resolved. But then at that point, `JSON.parse` would definitely be the way to go.

Comment: ...oh wait, maybe that's what you meant by `JSON encode`? Is that PHP?

Comment: @user1689607: yes precisely. PHP (like almost any server-side considered language) got a counter-part to "encode" data into JSON format.

Comment: Alright, I was confused by your wording when you wrote *"encode it into a native Javascript object/array"*. It's not really encoded into JavaScript, but rather into JSON that can be parsed into JavaScript. Just threw me off a little.

Comment: Thanks jAndy and gion_13. Both your awnsers worked fine. But jAndy's awnser is doing it correctly with parsing the JSON. But it's good to know how the replace format works. :)

Answer (score 2):

You should escape the special chars:

```
data_array[i].replace(/["[\]]/g,"");
```

Comment: just the close brace actually: `'quote:" open:[ close:]'.replace(/["[\]]/g,""); // "quote: open: close:"`

Comment: You're right, because special chars dont need to he escapes between square brackets. Thx